# both x and y variables are censored in a regression

Tags: r

Is there any existing routine in R to do Tobit regression model with both censored x and y varialbes? I know survreg function in survival pacakge can deal with censored response variables. What about the left censored x predictor variable?

Answer (score 2):

There is a framework for both for tobit regression and for "interval"-censored variables in the survival package. This is Therneau's example using Tobin's original data:

```
tfit <- survreg(Surv(durable, durable>0, type='left') ~age + quant,
                data=tobin, dist='gaussian')

predict(tfit,type="response")
```

And the `Surv` function will accept interval censoring.

Comment: What about censored predictor in this example? e.g., age is left censored?

Comment: I'm not sure age is a good example, because if you know age at any one time, you know it at all times. You can either censor during intervals with missing data for which you do not have a solid imputation strategy, or use some sort of multiple imputation method to "fill in".

Comment: THanks DWin for your quick response. Here is my situation:

Comment: THanks DWin for your quick response. You are right that age is probably not a good example. My question is simply to build a regression model between a right censored variable (response variable) and a left censored varialbe(predictor). I understand that the survival package can solve the response variable problem but wondering if there is anyway to deal with the censored predictor problem except imputation.